# How to get Bootstrap dropdown menu to work in ASP masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, master-pages

Getting excited about Bootstrap I am replacing the menu in our site's MasterPage. I got a nice menu to work in a test.aspx page, but when putting this in the masterpage, I observe that the hamburger icon for small screen does not show the drop down menus. Is this a primary limitation of the Bootstrap to Asp.Net combination, or am I doing something wrong here?

Here is the masterpage with just a basic version of the Bootstrap menu:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage1.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <title>Test with Bootstrap menu</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder_Header" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <nav id="menu_projects">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div id="menubar" class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" runat="server">
                                <ul id="ul_menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" runat="server">
                                    <li><a id="a_menu_1" href="#"></a>Menu 1</li>
                                    <li><a id="a_menu_2" href="#"></a>Menu 2</li>
                                    <li><a id="a_menu_3" href="#"></a>Menu 3</li>
                                    <li><a id="a_menu_4" href="#"></a>Menu 4</li>
                                    <li><a id="a_menu_5" href="#"></a>Menu 5</li>
                                    <li><a id="a_menu_6" href="#"></a>Menu 6</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder_Body" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here the actual page using the master page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Dev/MasterPage1.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MP1_menu_test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dev_MP1_menu_test" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_Header" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_Body" Runat="Server">
    <h1>This is a test with master age</h1>
</asp:Content>
```

The above combination does show the menu, but only on a large screen. When making the screen smaller, the hamburger icon replaces the menu items, but the hamburger does not show the drop down list of menu items.

I also tested with the same bootstrap menu code in a regular, non-masterpage, aspx page, which just works perfect, with working drop down:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="NoMP_menu_test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dev_NoMP_menu_test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <title>Test with Bootstrap menu</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav id="menu_projects">
                <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div id="menubar" class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" runat="server">
                            <ul id="ul_menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" runat="server">
                                <li><a id="a_menu_1" href="#"></a>Menu 1</li>
                                <li><a id="a_menu_2" href="#"></a>Menu 2</li>
                                <li><a id="a_menu_3" href="#"></a>Menu 3</li>
                                <li><a id="a_menu_4" href="#"></a>Menu 4</li>
                                <li><a id="a_menu_5" href="#"></a>Menu 5</li>
                                <li><a id="a_menu_6" href="#"></a>Menu 6</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <h1>Test without masterpage</h1>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

With all files, I left the code-behind pages completely empty, just left those as these were created by VisualStudio.

The version of .Net is 3.5.

Based on this test, it appears that the MasterPage breaks Bootstrap. But I find it hard to believe that such a useful package as Bootstrap cannot be utilized with a Asp Masterpage.

How else would I code a menu bar for a site with dozens of pages?

---

Commenter Jason is right: the ID values in the MasterPage are prefixed by the Asp system with something like `ctl100_`, which is surely the reason that the javascript in Bootstrap cannot find those.

Here is the relevant part as seen by the browser:

```
            <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div id="menubar" class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="ctl00_navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul id="ctl00_ul_menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a id="a_menu_1" href="#"></a>Menu 1</li>
                            <li><a id="a_menu_2" href="#"></a>Menu 2</li>
                            <li><a id="a_menu_3" href="#"></a>Menu 3</li>
                            <li><a id="a_menu_4" href="#"></a>Menu 4</li>
                            <li><a id="a_menu_5" href="#"></a>Menu 5</li>
                            <li><a id="a_menu_6" href="#"></a>Menu 6</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Two IDs are modified by IIS/ASP to ctl100_navbar and ctl100_ul_menu.

I tried to change the data-target to `#ctl100_navbar` but that did not help.

How to work around this?

Comment: Open your browser's javascript console, then try clicking the hamburger menu again.  Observe the console to see if you get any javascript errors.  It's been ages I used ASPX, but I believe the ID's or names of the HTML elements get changed dynamically so javascript can't find them.

Comment: @JasonRoner tried it, no errors. I will try to compare the view-source of both aspx pages in firefox for changed ID names

Comment: Try moving any js scripts from <head> to the end right before </body> as well

Comment: @JasonRoner Tried this too, but no improvement.

Comment: Set ClientIDMode to static https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @WithMetta Good tip! I'll have to upgrade the web site to .Net 4, I will try this tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the helpful hints of commenters I found a two simple solutions.

The suggestion for adding the attribute `ClientMode="static"` is useful. In my case, with .Net version 3.5, there is no such attribute, so this would mean to upgrade to .Net version 4.

However, in .Net 4, the default for ClientMode is Predictable, which is just as useful as static. So there is no need to add this attribute.

All together, the solution is to upgrade to .Net 4, without adding the ClientMode attribute.

With the unchanged files as posted in a .Net 4 project, the Bootstrap Menu Dropdown works fine.

I tested that even with a second MasterPage, the menu dropdown in the .Net4 project works fine without a ClientMode attrib.

---

The other option, when staying with .Net 3.5, is to `predict` that the `id="navbar"` is mangled by IIS/ASP to `id="ctl01_navbar"` and to use that same prefixed id in the `data-target` attribute. I just tested that that makes the dropdown working for me.

Advantage: less work in the short term, no need to upgrade to .Net4, with all the trouble of testing if all features of the site keep working.

Disadvantage: problems on the long term: if we ever upgrade to .Net4, we will probably have forgotten about the workaround, so that upgrade will break the Bootstrap dropdown. But also if another MasterPage is added to the system, or removed, the number in the prefix may change.

In my case, after copying MasterPage1 to MasterPage2, the prefix changed from `ctl01_`, to `ctl00_` for both masterpages.